# I try to launch Spyder from Anaconda Navigator, but i obtained this error message

Tags: anaconda, spyder

libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open crocus: /usr/lib/dri/crocus_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: crocus
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

could you help me?, its been almost a year i can't use spyder, uninstall and reinstall even anaconda and spyder

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Thank you